# Bootstrap col-md-4 h2 not centering on mobile

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using rails to make a simple shopping app that displays a list of products. On the mobile view when the product stack into 1 long list instead of a row of 3, the product h2 tags are not centering, and are floating to the right for some reason. The first h2 tag centers fine, but the rest float to the right and do not center correctly. I've tried everything related to css that I can think of like

- `text-align: center;`
- `margin-bottom: 10px;`
- `text-center`
- thinking it might be floating because it is too close together?

Here is my html and css

```
<div class="row text-center">
        <% @products.each do |product| %>
          <div class="product col-md-4 text-center">
           <h2><%= link_to product.name, product_path(product) %></h2>
            <%= link_to image_tag(product.image_file_name, product_path(product), :class => 'img-responsive' %>
            <div class="product-info">
                <div class="product-info-left"><%=product.descrip %></div>
                <div class="product-info-right">$<%=product.price %></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Css

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
    .product-page, .product-show {
        padding-top: 2px;
    }

    .product-info-right, .product-info-left {
        margin-bottom: 10 !important;
    }

    .product > h2{
        text-align: center !important;
    }
}

    .product-info-left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive; 
    font-size: 15px;
}

.product-info-right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

.product img {
    height: 200px !important;
    width: 250px !important;
}

.product h2 {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.product > h2 > a {
    color: black !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1e9b69;
}
```

My thinking was maybe this was happening because the elements were too close together and were being floated right by default, but I have tried to correct that behavior through the margin, float, and text-align, and still nothing. Any help or suggestions of what I might be doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you have `h2` but in styles you try to center `h1` on line

```
.product > h1{
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

There has to be

```
.product > h2 {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: @JamesN: I don't use bootstrap, cn you please create a fiddle where I can see the problem and find better code fix for you?

Comment: I appreciate the offer :) but I stupidly forgot I a `</div>` T_T